# Не работает like в yii2 searchmodel

Tags: php, yii2

нужно что бы при записи города, страны, области работал запрос по like , а не точному запросу

> $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'country', $this->country])

```
<?php

namespace common\models\search;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use common\models\Order;

/**
 * ArticleSearch represents the model behind the search form about `common\models\Article`.
 */
class OrderSearch extends Order
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id'], 'integer'],
            [['id', 'carrying', 'type_truck', 'country'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Order::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'carrying' => $this->carrying,
            'type_truck' => $this->type_truck,
            'country' => $this->country,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'country', $this->country])
            /*->andFilterWhere(['like', 'title', $this->title])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'body', $this->body])*/;

        return $dataProvider;
    }


    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'type_truck' => 'Тип транспорта',
            'carrying' => 'Грузоподъемность',
            'country' => 'Город / область'

        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было писать просто:

```
$query->filterWhere(['like', 'country', $this->country])
```

Так он берет только те которые принял в $this->country, а раньше был условник and

Answer (score 1):

```
['like', 'name', '%tester', false]
```

сгенерирует SQL

```
name LIKE '%tester'
```

То есть, нужно просто написать

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'country', '%'.$this->country.'%',false])
```

[Документация](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where()-detail).

Comment: Если Вы хотите добавку к рейтингу, то ИМХО, ответ все же лучше писать по русски.